# Commutive property of the Bra-ket notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

I'm struggling when it comes to understanding the commutive properties of the Bra-ket notation in quantum mechanics. I understand how to work with constants, bra and kets. However, the second I start introducing eigen-equations such as
$$\hat{x}|x'\rangle = x'|x'\rangle$$
to solve problems like
$$\langle\psi_p|\hat{x}|x'\rangle = x'\psi_p^*(x')$$
I instantly lose grip on the rules for the Bra-ket notation.
Am I allowed to simply pull the $x'$ out of the bracket like this: $\langle\psi_p|x'|x'\rangle=x'\langle\psi_p|x'\rangle$?

My book only state the rules for operators between a **bra** and a **ket**, $\langle a|\boldsymbol{A}|b\rangle$, but not how to handle problem including eigen-equations such as this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When writing $\hat x\vert x'\rangle=x'\vert x'\rangle$, the $x'$ is actually a number (aka a scalar) and so can be moved about like a regular number, so that
$$
\langle \psi_p\vert\hat x\vert x'\rangle = 
\langle \psi_p \vert x'\vert x'\rangle = x'\langle\psi_p\vert x'\rangle 
$$
because $x'\in \mathbb{R}$, much in the way that $\langle b\vert 3\vert b\rangle=3\langle a\vert b\rangle$.

Indeed if $\hat A\vert b\rangle = \alpha \vert c\rangle +\beta \vert f\rangle$ then
$$
\langle a\vert \hat A\vert b\rangle= 
\langle a\vert\left[\alpha \vert c\rangle +\beta \vert f\rangle\right]
=
\langle a\vert\alpha \vert c\rangle +\langle a\vert \beta \vert f\rangle
=\alpha \langle a\vert c\rangle +\beta \langle a\vert f\rangle.
$$

Comment: Okai, great, but for clarity, is $\langle A|3|B\rangle = \langle A| \cdot 3 \cdot |B\rangle$? And if there is an operator instead  $\langle A|\boldsymbol{A}|B\rangle = \langle A| \cdot \boldsymbol{A} \cdot |B\rangle$

Comment: not sure why you need the $"\cdot" $ in there since $3$ is a scalar.

Comment: Oh, so more like $\langle A|3|B\rangle = \langle A| \cdot 3 |B\rangle$?

Comment: The bra vector already implicitly contains a dot product so there is no need for "$\cdot$" in there.  In terms of usual vector one would have, for instance, 
$\langle a\vert \to \vec a\cdot$ so that $\langle a\vert b\rangle=\vec a\cdot \vec b$.

Comment: *Extra note*: It could also be viewed as follows. It is hidden in the fact that one can write $\hat{x}= x\hat{1}$ in the position representation. Therefore the $x$ is a scalar and can be pulled out of the bracket and the identity maps $|\Psi \rangle$ to $|\Psi \rangle$.

Comment: I just came across the following notation $|j,m\rangle$ in regards of angular momentum, and $|\frac{1}{2},\pm \frac{1}{2}\rangle$ for spin. How should I interpret this?

Comment: @PhyCoMath I’m not sure I understand.  The first entry is the value of $j$ and the second the value of $m$.  You need to specify both values to completely specify an angular momentum state.

Comment: Aaaah, so its like $\Psi_{n,j,m} = |n,j,m\rangle$?